# Python: data unmatched in csv output

Tags: python, csv

Let's say I have two csv outputs look like:

> mark1 :
>
> [['a', '', '', '', '', ''], ['b', '', '', '', '', ''], ['c', '', '', '', '', ''], ['d', '', '', '', '', ''], ['e', '', '', '', '', ''], ['f', '', '', '', '', ''], ['g', '', '', '', '', '']]

and

> mark2:
>
> [['a', '10', '', '', '', ''], ['b', '', '', '', '', ''], ['c', '10', '', '', '', ''], ['d', '', '', '', '', ''], ['e', '7', '', '', '', ''], ['m', '9', '', '', '', ''], ['n', '', '', '', '', '']]

In this case m and n cannot be found in the first csv output.
so the code I've written to find out those two is:

> mark1[row][0] != mark2[row1][0]:
>
> ```
>             print 'some marks are not the same - no match found'
> ```

The code above is not working.

Is there any specific way to solute this problem?

Thanks.

Comment: How are you assigning the values for `row` and `row1`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'll preface this by saying I voted for @ThaneBrimhall's answer, but in the interests of showing all kinds of ways (and assuming that you only care if one element is in the other, regardless of the position):

```
# Get a set of unique first elements for each list
set1 = set([n[0] for n in mark1])
set2 = set([n[0] for n in mark2])

# Items in mark1 but not mark2
if set1.difference(set2):
  print 'some marks are not the same - no match found'

# Items in mark2 but not mark1
if set2.difference(set1):
  print 'some marks are not the same - no match found'
```

And if you want to see which ones caused errors:

```
# Get a set of unique first elements for each list
set1 = set([n[0] for n in mark1])
set2 = set([n[0] for n in mark2])

# Items in mark1 but not mark2
set1_diffs = set1.difference(set2)
if set1_diffs:
  print 'Marks {0} in mark1 but not mark2'.format(list(set1_diffs))

# Items in mark2 but not mark1
set2_diffs = set2.difference(set1)
if set2_diffs:
  print 'Marks {0} in mark2 but not mark1'.format(list(set2_diffs))
```

Answer (score 2):

The easiest (and computationally fastest) way I found to do this would be to do something like this:

```
if [n for n in mark2 if n[0] not in [m[0] for m in mark1]]:
    print 'some marks are not found...'
```

It takes two for loops to compare each of the values you want to iterate over. The code above roughly translates into:

```
keys = []
for m in mark1:
    keys.append(m[0])
for n in mark2:
    if n not in keys:
        print 'some marks not found...'
        break
```

Answer (score 0):

Given you want to compare the entire list of lists this should compare them:

```
 if mark1 != mark2:
      print 'some are not the same...'
```

If you wanted to compare just the first field of each list in the lists this is the way to do that.

```
def compare_first(mark1,mark2):
  for row in mark1:
    for row2 in mark2:
      if row[0] != row2[0]:
        return false;
  return true
```

then in main use that function

```
if !equal_firs(mark1,mark2):
  print('some are not the same...')
```

Answer (score 0):

your example doesn't make much sense.

```
mark1= [['a', '', '', '', '', ''], ['b', '', '', '', '', ''], ['c', '', '', '', '', ''], ['d', '', '', '', '', ''], ['e', '', '', '', '', ''], ['f', '', '', '', '', ''], ['g', '', '', '', '', '']]
mark2= [['a', '10', '', '', '', ''], ['b', '', '', '', '', ''], ['c', '10', '', '', '', ''], ['d', '', '', '', '', ''], ['e', '7', '', '', '', ''], ['m', '9', '', '', '', ''], ['n', '', '', '', '', '']]
if mark1[row][0] != mark2[row1][0]:
    print 'some marks are not the same - no match found'
```

in that if statement, you're addressing row and row1 -- why aren't you looking in the same row ?

aside from that, this isn't correct-

```
mark1[row][0] != mark2[row1][0]:
```

i believe you meant:

```
if mark1[row][0] != mark2[row1][0]:
```